# Basic geometry question

Tags: geometry

I've come across this problem in my textbook:

> Given this square, prove that $AO=2OD$, if $ED$ and $AF$ are perpendicular, $BE=EC$, $CF=FD$.
>
> [image],

I would appreciate any help or hints!

Comment: Triangles $AOD$ and $ADF$ are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try showing that AOE and ADF are similar triangles.

Comment: Big hint: Notice AOD is similar to ADF

Comment: Don't they also need to have same ratio? They have 1 common side (ratio of 1) but other 2 don't seem to have the same ratio; am I wrong?

Comment: AOD is similar to ADF. Thus AO/OD = AD/DF. Are you asking why they are similar? In that case, try looking at the angles

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/814261)

Comment: @lioness99a I think I just gave hints, which is what the question asked for. Can you elaborate on what I should have done?

Comment: @IsaacBrowne Your answer basically tells the OP to go and read the other comments, and therefore is not an answer in itself

Comment: @lioness99a Oh, sorry, I meant to say the comments on this answer, because I wanted to provide a hint and then a bigger hint.

Comment: @IsaacBrowne You would be better off editing your answer to add the hints once you have had the discussion with the OP. Comments are more likely to be deleted than answers

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Since $\triangle ADO \sim \triangle DFO$, $\dfrac {AO}{OD} = \dfrac {2}{1}$ implies $\dfrac {DO}{OF} = \dfrac {2}{1}$.

Since $\triangle DCE \sim \triangle DOF$, $\dfrac {DC}{CE} = \dfrac {DO}{OF}$.

∴$\dfrac {DC}{CE} = \dfrac {2}{1}$, which is the first requitred result.

The second required result follows from the fact that $\triangle ADF \cong \triangle DCE$.